# Running Wordpress/NGINX from different path

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

Im learning NGINX, so any help is really appreciated.

I have the frontend of a website running as the root of mysite.com, and now I want to run wordpress from mysite.com/blog.

My file structure is:
/srv/mysite/frontend
/srv/mysite/wordpress

this is the error i've been getting from the nginx logs

`2020/03/29 00:09:03 [error] 23049#23049: *39 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: XXXXXXX, server: www.mysite.com, request: "GET /api HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "mysite.com"`

and this is my nginx config file so far

```
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com;
    charset utf-8;

    location ^~ /blog {
        root /srv/mysite/wordpress;
    }

   location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location / {
        root /srv/mysite/frontend/dist;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message shows either the wrong path of the sock file or the permissions. Make sure the php sock file exists in the path `/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock` and change the permissions of the file.

```
For Debian

chown -R  wwww-data:www-data /run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock

For Rhel

chown -R nginx:nginx /run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock
```

Also, you can try this config.

```
   location /blog {
        root /srv/mysite/wordpress;
    }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
```